# Show annotations in PDF

Tags: pdf, evince

I have a PDF file that has annotations in them. Comments that are in a box show up, but removed words or other insertions do not appear. I don't need to add any annotations; I just need to view them. Can this be done using Evince? Or do I need an other PDF reader?

Comment: I would suggest to use `okular`, it's rather feature-rich and may help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks but not using KDE I rather not use Okular... is this the only PDF reader that can show annotations?? Anything more lightweight would be great.